# Assistance on function call in verilog

Tags: verilog, function-call

I am trying to understand a NoC arbiter code. when I try to do a syntax check using Xilinx sofware I'm getting an error "Function calls such as to 'log2' are not supported in constant expressions" for the line "localparam ARBITER_BIN_WIDTH= log2(ARBITER_WIDTH);". What changes shoud be done to this line? 
The part of the code where I am facing the problem:

```
 parameter ARBITER_WIDTH    =4
      input integer number; begin   
      log2=0;   
      while(2**log2<number) begin   
        log2=log2+1;    
     end    
   end  
 endfunction // log2 

localparam ARBITER_BIN_WIDTH= log2(ARBITER_WIDTH);
```

Comment: Can you describe that log2 function ?

Comment: Without more details on the code, its hard to say for sure, but the tool is complaing that it doesnt support function calls to get compile-time constants like parameters; ie, it isnt able to run the function `log2` to get a compile-time value for `ARBITER_BIN_WIDTH`. If its Vivado, you should have SystemVerilog support which should let you use `$clog2()` in its place to get roughly the same functionality.

Comment: @Zuzu: can you update in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See IEEE Standard Verilog® Hardware Description Language LRM, at 10.2.5, they have described the function for Log

```
function integer clogb2;
 input depth;
 integer i,result;
 begin
 for (i = 0; 2 ** i < depth; i = i + 1)
   result = i + 1;
   clogb2 = result;
 end
 endfunction
```

Can you confirm that, is it working for you?

Comment: does the error "Function calls such as to 'log2' are not supported in constant expressions" mean lefthand side and right hand side of the expression do not match the type?

Comment: Yes! It is highly recommended that, bit width must be same.

Comment: what is the size supported by localparm?

Comment: you can give it as `parameter [31:0] ARBITER_WIDTH = 32'h4`, or as `parameter integer ARBITER_WIDTH = 32'd4`.

Comment: can you please have a look
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42065585/open-source-rtl-architecture-of-products-on-mipi